# Can't use mobs decorator, error:Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, package.json, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to use mobx decorators, I had no problem installing and using it with react native before but now I am developing a website using React.Js library and it gives me this error.

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (25:1):

  23 | 
  24 | 
> 25 | @observer
     | ^
  26 | class Recomended extends Component{
  27 |   constructor(props) {
  28 |     super(props);
```

Can anyone please help to make it work.

Below is my package.Json:

```
{
  "name": "airingbot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@createjs/tweenjs": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "babel-plugin-mobx-deep-action": "^1.6.1",
    "es6-tween": "^5.5.10",
    "mobx": "^5.14.2",
    "mobx-react": "^6.1.4",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "three-orbit-controls": "^82.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators-legacy",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: React does not [encourage using decorators](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/can-i-use-decorators/) and [mobx knows it](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think these steps may help to add decorator support to a React application created with `create-react-app`:

1. `npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`
2. Replace `react-scripts` with `react-app-rewired` in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",
  ...
}
```

3. Create a new file `config-overrides.js` at the root of the project and copy the next content:

```js
const { override, addDecoratorsLegacy } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(addDecoratorsLegacy())
```